# Is "It's the worst thing we can do before we went to sleep" correct?

Tags: grammaticality

I heard (and read on subtitles) the sentence in a TED talk.
I think the sentence should be "It's the worst thing we can do before we go to sleep" and I don't understand why the past tense of go is used.

Comment: Without a link to the source I don't see what we can say here apart from *You're probably right.* But it's not easy to see how auto-generated subtitles could make such a mistake, and it's very unlikely a native speaker would actually *say* what you've transcribed.in your title.

Comment: I agree with @FumbleFingers.  It's wrong and you're right to call it.

Comment: It was the worst thing [...] before we went to sleep. It is the worst thing [...] before we go to sleep or before going to sleep. Often, speech is sloppy  is the short answer.

Comment: Also, acceptable: It's the worst thing [[present] we could have done [past] before going to sleep/before we went to sleep. That back shift is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A) It's [present] the worst thing **we can do** [present]:

- **before we go to sleep [present]**

- **before going to sleep [participle/gerund form]**

B) It's [present] the worst thing **we could do** [past]:

- **before we went to sleep** [past]

- **before going to sleep** [participle/gerund form]

The verb pattterns have to be:

**present in main clause + present + present**

OR

**present  in the main clause + past + past**.

It's the worst thing [present] we can do [present] before we went to sleep [past] is not standard.

I**t's fine to have a present in the main and back shift both the  others.** **It's not fine to have a present in the main clause and back shift in only one verb in the second clause.** **It would be usual for speakers to mix up the back shift in one verb and not the other.**

That said, speakers speak spontaneously when doing public speaking or being interviewed. Therefore, one does fine irregularities in speech that might not normally be found in a speaker's speech patterns.

I **like** the friends **we have** and the place where **we live**.
I **like** the friends **we had** and the place where **we lived**.

I like the friends we **had** and the place **we live**. [not usual at all, to back shift one verb and not the other.]

Answer (score 2):

Usually the verb forms go like this:

*Present - present* (talking about something that people sometimes do):
It's the worst thing we *can* do before we *go* to sleep.

*Conditional - simple past* (talking about something that people might do):
It's the worst thing we *could* do before we *went* to sleep.

Comment: I agree but I also would like to point out that in spontaneous speech mistakes often occur that would not occur in written form.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the TED Talk at hand, but that sentence would be idiomatic if it is referring to a hypothetical scenario, the backshift of tense to **went** expressing a form of *irrealis*.  As Michael Harvey put it, "talking about something that people *might* do".

Comment: It's simply agrammatical, anyway you look at it. That said, when people speak, they often make mistakes that they might  not make in other circumstances such as writing.

Comment: I don't think it's as simple as that at all. If you're looking for something ungrammatical, **can** should be **could**.

Comment: I see no universe in which the OP's question is grammatical. Yes, **can **should be **could**. Then, it would work. That specific back shifting would work.

Comment: @Lambie: I must live in a county that is frozen in time. The true "locals" whose grandparents and great-grandparents lived here too, say things like that all the time. We backshift all over the place.